# NFA that doesn't accept a language

Tags: automata

Suppose I want to draw a NFA that doesn't accept a language containing $aba$. Would this work:

[image]

Comment: No, that one accepts *all* words over $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Construct the obvious four-state NFA with minimum number of transitions, which DOES accept 'aba' (and no other string).  Complete it as a DFA by adding a 'dead' state, then adding all missing transitions from the other states to the dead state, plus two transitions from the dead state - one on 'a' back to the second NFA state, one on 'b' back to the third NFA state.  Now invert the finality - i.e change each final state to non-final and each non-final state to final.  You now have an NFA (DFA, actually) which accepts all strings not containing 'aba'.

Comment: The method you suggest, from NFA to DFA and then complement, is correct. The way you build the DFA (with transitions from the dead state back into the main states) does not work for me.